# display only last message from each user

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Hello friends i want to display the last message from each user in this table, lets assume the `$_SESSION['id']` is 1 so i want to display the last messages by each from or to user 1 here is my query:

`SELECT * FROM message WHERE (msg_from='1') OR (msg_to='1') GROUP BY msg_from,msg_to ORDER BY MAX(msg_id) DESC`

but when i run this it displays two messages from a user that is in the msg_from column and also in the msg_to column and it doesn't display the last inserted message, please guys, I need help.

Comment: You need to select either `msg_from` or `msg_to`, you can't put both at same time.

Answer (score 0):

since you are ordering by `MAX(msg_id) DESC` then you reqire only the first result because it will be the latest then you may do something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM message where msg_id IN (SELECT msg_id FROM message WHERE (msg_from='1') OR (msg_to='1') GROUP BY msg_from,msg_to ORDER BY MAX(msg_id) DESC);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM message where msg_id IN (SELECT msg_id FROM message WHERE (msg_from='1') OR (msg_to='1') GROUP BY msg_from,msg_to ORDER BY MAX(msg_id) DESC) LIMIT 1;
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Fetching the last messages for user-1 from others:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE msg_to = '1'
GROUP BY msg_from ORDER BY msg_date DESC
```

Fetching the last messages from user-1 to others:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE msg_from = '1'
GROUP BY msg_to ORDER BY msg_date DESC
```

---

I didn't use your `MAX(msg_id)` for ordering the data, instead, I used the date to get the latest messages.